# How to run a .war File after building my Web Application in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I made a small web application using `Netbeans`, it contains some `JSP pages`. Anyway, when I built the project it created a folder called `dist` and inside it there's a `.war file`. How do I run it? When creating my application I used `GlassFish Server` and `JavaDB` for Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps;

- Log in to glassfish at :http://localhost:4848/ (typically) providing
  the user name and password.
- Click on the applications on the common tasks on left frame of
  browser and then click on the deploy button to bring in the Deploy
  Applications or Modules screen.
- Click on the browse button to locate your war or alternatively you
  can choose any local packaged file or directory check box to locate
  your application archive or directory. Remember the type of the
  application is a mandatory field which you have to choose otherwise
  you can't proceed further.
- Click "Ok" to deploy. Once successful, it takes you to application
  page, there you can see Launch, Redeploy and Restart depending the
  application type.  If you want to undeploy or enable/disable
  particular application you can do so by selecting the check box and
  then click the desired button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy the war to your application server in order to run it.

Comment: And how do I do that exactly?